# Is a continuous monotone function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

So this is a quiz question that asked if the following statement is true or false:

> $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a one-one and continuous function, then the function is of bounded variation.

Apparently the answer provided was $False$ with example being $x\sin(1/x)$ on $[0,1]$.

But, this is not one one on $[0,1]$, as I can conclude from the graph of the function.

> My doubt is: I think that the function is of bounded variation as monotone continuous functions are of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ and given that the function is one-one, it must be strictly monotone and continuous.

Any clarification is highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the function is not one-to-one (which is what I'm guessing you mean by "one-one"?). For example, $\frac{1}{\pi}$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ both give the function value $0$. Maybe @dfnu wants to weigh in here, because they seem more confident about this answer?

Comment: @dfnu $\sqrt{x}$ is BV on $[0,1]$...

Comment: Go with your doubts on this one. As you say, monotone functions on $[a,b]$ are BV.  Continuous one-one functions on $[a,b]$ are monotone.  Therefore ...

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Thanks for the comment, I found that this need not be true if the function is not bounded, as we can take $f(x)= \tan(x)$ on $[0,\pi / 2]$ and this is not bounded hence not a function of bounded variation.

Comment: @Kashif $\tan x$ is not defined on $\pi/2$

Comment: @B.S.Thomson so here we can say that continuous one one function on $[a,b]$ is also of bounded variation. So the answer should be true?